# Chrome asks for proxy authentication for every page I open, IE doesn't

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, authentication, proxy, proxy-authentication

Chrome used to run properly, when all of sudden it started asking for my proxy's username and password on every page I open. After I enter them, I see the page, but then I need to type them again whenever I open another link.

Chrome (last version) is behind my university's proxy, whose address is configured in Win7 "lan settings". IE works fine. I Restarted Chrome, but it didn't help.

What could it be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings.

Scroll down to "**+ Show advanced settings**" and click it.

Scroll down until you see "**Network**," and click "**Change proxy settings...**"

Once you get there, you should see a dialog box similar to what would pop in IE's settings, and you're going to click the "**Connections**" tab.

In that tab, you'll see near the lower right-hand corner "**LAN Settings**," click it.

Once loaded, at the bottom, if the "**Proxy server**" box is checked, *uncheck* it and see if that works.

Comment: I think your solution worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with VPN and you need to set proxy on and off then you can try some **chrome extension** to set the username and password automatically.

e.g., **"proxy auto auth"** or **"proxy helper"**.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling hardware acceleration in chrome helped me

[click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPKLu.png)